# Finding the second point of intersection from a normal on a hyperbola

Tags: coordinate-systems, hyperbolic-geometry

The question is phrased as follows:

"A rectangular hyperbola, W, has equation xy = 12"

a) Show that the gradient of the normal, N, to W at the point P(2,6), is 1/3.

b) Hence find an equation for N/

c) Find the coordinates of the point Q where N intersects the curve W again.

My solution for a) & b) was the linear equation 3y = x + 16, but using the information provided I'm quite lost as to the other point of intersection...a simplified solution would be met with much gratification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found the equation of the normal line $\:y=\frac{x+16}{3}\:$, which is correct.

In order to find the points of intersection with the hyperbola $\:y=\frac{12}{x}\:$ simply write that both $\:y\:$ are equal :
$$y=\frac{x+16}{3}=\frac{12}{x}$$
$$x^2+16x-36=0$$
Solve it for $\:x\:$. You will found two roots :

First $\:x=2\:$ is obvious since it is already known that the normal line is issued from the point $\;(x=2\:,\:y=6)\:$

Second $\:x=-18\:$ and then $\:y=\frac{12}{x}=-\frac{2}{3}$